# How to deserialize json with key contains "." in C#?

Tags: c#, json

I want to create class to deserialize following JSON. I have tried with http://json2csharp.com/ but it doesn't work.

JSON

```
{
    "usertoken": "TqasdfgdSz0UleD-hdST5sigIE1MdOlKQ2HXrcvTwtCpveN9Fm",
    "expires_sec": 12095,
    "user": "testuser.com",
    ".expired": "Sat, 2 Jun 2018 09:25:00 GMT"
}
```

Tried with following class but issue in `.expired` class member

```
public class Authentication
{
    public string usertoken { get; set; }
    public int expires_sec { get; set; }
    public string user { get; set; }
    public string .expired { get; set; }    //.will not work here
}
```

Please suggest

Comment: Improvement suggestion for your next question: "Doesn't work" is not a very good problem description. In your case, "doesn't compile with the following error message: ..." (or: "doesn't compile because C# identifiers cannot contain a dot", if you already know that) would be much better. Otherwise: Good question, good title!

Comment: This may help you.
[Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on right track. All you need to use is `JsonProperty`. It will help you to define the property name that your program will use and name that your json string will use during serialization and deserialization operations.

Check following sample.

```
public class Authentication
{
    public string usertoken { get; set; }
    public int expires_sec { get; set; }
    public string user { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty (".expired")]
    public string expired { get; set; }
}
```

You need to install **Newtonsoft.Json** nuget package to achieve this.